# Making c# Windows form tool public

Tags: c#, forms, public

I was just wondering if it is safe make Windows Form tools (like textbox, buttons etc.) public. It appears as private on the Designer.cs file. I changed it to public and it still worked but I am worried because sometime messing with default setting is something I should not do even if it works.

Comment: If you are happy with the risks of it being `public` (i.e. it is `public`, so any other class can fiddle with it), sure - go right ahead.

Comment: The access modifiers for individual widgets can be changed in the Designer window under Properties (I think) -- no need to edit the .designer.cs file

Comment: Consider [why they made them private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) before you do much

Comment: Consider searching for questions that deal with the underlying reason you want to do this, and consider asking that question if it hasn't already been asked. There is a nearly 100% chance there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do than making form widgets public.

Comment: As a compromise, you can make them protected, which will force whoever uses it to subclass it before monkeying with the individual controls. This communicates the intention that the controls are meant to be manipulated from within the class, but still allows an advanced developer to have the flexibility.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm not sure that's a "compromise" in this situation. For people at this knowledge level, I think it would only encourage them to make further design mistakes by subclassing a form just to get access to the widgets. Instead, almost certainly an alternate design pattern is called for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly *safe* to change the modifier on controls to `public`-- just as changing fields or properties or methods on any other class from private to public would be *safe*.  You won't suddenly find that something breaks, fails, locks up, etc.  It just means that the control can now be accessed from outside your form.

However, the default setting of `private` for controls helps encourage better code design.  If you find you need to make a control `public`, then you are probably not separating our the concerns of your form from the rest of your application well-- or at least not following what the general community feels is a good pattern.

For example, if you need to modify the text of a label-- you shouldn't need to expose the label itself as public.  You could choose instead to make a public property of your form that sets the private label's text value.  For example, if your label is meant to represent the subtitle of the form:

```
public string Subtitle { 
   get { return label1.Text; }
   set { label1.Text = value; }
}
```

Even better, your form could listen to events or notifications from some intermediate object and update the label internally based on those notifications:

```
private void someobject_SubtitleChanged(object sender, SubtitleChangedEventArgs args) {
   label1.Text = args.Subtitle;
}
```